# Django/Python convert float during list comprehension

Tags: python, django, floating-point

I have a Django Queryset object called `data` containing string keys and float values.

I want to convert all floats to 2 decimal places.

If I do this:

```
>>> param1_values = [d[param1] for d in data]
>>> param1_values[:5]
[26.1, 24.6, 26.2444444444444, 27.3103448275862, 26.7576923076923]
```

...which is fine but I need to float to two decimal places.

However, if I do this:

```
>>> param1_values = ["%.2f" % d['mean_air_temp'] for d in data]
>>> param1_values[:5]
['26.10', '24.60', '26.24', '27.31', '26.76']
```

The numbers are what I wanted but they are converted to strings! Why does this occur and how do I solve it?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What purpose does it serve to store the numbers in rounded form?

Comment: In answer to your other question, *Why does this occur?*, it occurs because when the first argument to the `%` operator is a string (`'%.2f'`) the result is always a string, similar to how in another language you might use `printf`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`round`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#round) function:

```
param1_values = [round(d[param1], 2) for d in data]
```

> Note: The behavior of round() for floats can be surprising: for
>   example, round(2.675, 2) gives 2.67 instead of the expected 2.68. This
>   is not a bug: it’s a result of the fact that most decimal fractions
>   can’t be represented exactly as a float. See [Floating Point
>   Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues) for more information.

This seems to be accurate enough for your use case.  If you need a more precise answer see [Ignacio's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9999513/186868) response using Decimal.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: And why would that be? A comment like that is hardly helpful (even if it might be correct).

Comment: Well, this "works" as long as you understand floating point arithmetic. But OP may be confused by answers like `[26.100000000000001, …]`

Comment: @kojiro: That's a different problem, though. Agreed that it doesn't make much sense to round the floats themselves instead of only rounding them if it's really necessary (like on display)

Comment: @Darwin: Depends on the input. What do you want to achieve by that?

Comment: ok - I'm confused. I get good results with the first answer, which works. Is there some reason I should not use this solution?

Comment: @Darwin: Rounding the decimal representation of floating point numbers doesn't make a lot of sense, as they can't be represented precisely in binary. If you are not familiar with the issues that come with floats, you should better use the `decimal` module. The question remains: Why do you need this? We can probably give you a much better answer if you tell us your goal.

Comment: @Niklas B - I am rounding the numbers for graphing output. The results  are mean averages anyway, so accuracy is not paramount beyond 2 places, and the output is much more readable at 2 places than the raw means.

Comment: @Darwin: Fair enough, in this case this is a perfectly valid solution :) You should accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Due to [unavoidable inaccuracies in IEEE 754 floating point representation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), it is impossible to solve this while keeping them floats.

```
>>> l = [26.1, 24.6, 26.2444444444444, 27.3103448275862, 26.7576923076923]
>>> [decimal.Decimal(x).quantize(decimal.Decimal('0.1')) for x in l]
[Decimal('26.1'), Decimal('24.6'), Decimal('26.2'), Decimal('27.3'), Decimal('26.8')]
```

The appropriate field to use in Django if you want to store these is [`DecimalField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield) (unless you're using SQLite, but that's a whole other kettle of fish).

Comment: +1: Thanks for coming back and doing this.  He wants to decimal points so it should be `decimal.Decimal('0.01')`

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the values rounded, or are you simply wanting to display two values after the decimal point when displaying the values in a template?  If you are working on a display issue, use the ['floatformat' filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat).  Again, if this is what you're trying to accomplish, I believe that as you roll through the list you can use "listitem|floatformat:-2" to get the desired result.  If, instead, you wish to store and use the rounded version in Python, you'll [not have an easy time of it](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Comment: Just re-read the original post, and you may want "listitem|floatformat:2".  This will display two values after the decimal, even if both are zero.  The '-2' option in the original will only show values after the decimal if it is necessary to describe the full value rounded to two decimal places.